# Проблема с arguments.callee в рекурсивной функции

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток ребята, вот интересная задачка. Пока не могу найти на нее ответ. Есть Объект `findSolution`, в нем объявлено свойство `this.find` с функцией. Вот код:

```
var findSolution = function(tar)
{

    this.target = tar;      
    this.find = function()
            {       
            if(arguments[0] == this.target)
                return arguments[1];
            else if(arguments[0] > this.target)
                {
                return null;    
                }   
            else{
                return this.find(arguments[0] + 5, "("+arguments[1]+" +5)") || 
                        this.find(arguments[0] * 3, "("+arguments[1]+" *3)");
                }   
            }
        };


var fs = new findSolution(24);  
console.log(fs.find(1,"1"));
```

Все работает классно. А вот когда рекурсивно вызываю функцию с помощью `arguments.callee`, выводится следующая ошибка:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

В чем вопрос я не могу разобраться пока. По идее должно все срабатывать.

А и еще более странно. Когда этот алгоритм объявлен не в объекте а просто как обыкновенная функция, даже с `arguments.callee` работает. Вот так работает, а внутри объекта выводится вышеуказанная ошибка.

```
var find = function()
        {

        if(arguments[0] == 24)
            return arguments[1];
        else if(arguments[0] > 24)
            {
            return null;    
            }   
        else{
            return arguments.callee(arguments[0] + 5, "("+arguments[1]+" +5)") || 
                    arguments.callee(arguments[0] * 3, "("+arguments[1]+" *3)");
            }   
        }

console.log(find(1,"1"));
```

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так заработает (без `.call` свойство target искалось у `arguments`):

```
return arguments.callee.call(this, …)
```

Comment: Действительно! Так почему arguments.callee не ухватывает контекст? ведь он вызывает текущую функцию внутри объекта.

Comment: Ну, `this` в JS не столько контекст, сколько объект, функция из поля которого была вызвана через точку. Некий синтаксический сахар, не имеющий под собой никакой специальной логики. Проще всего воспринимать именно так, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Спасибо! Контексты в JavaScript-е это такая же тонкость как и указатели в С/С++. Если овладеешь этим, остальное пойдет по маслу.

Comment: @ДудаШевченко почему не ухватывает? `arguments.callee(...)` - это вызов метода `callee` у объекта `arguments`! Его и ухватывает.

Comment: Хорошо, но он не ухватывает объект в котором вызывается. По этому и теряется контекст. Я исхожу из того, что arguments.callee вызывает текущую функцию, но не берет контекст в котором она выполняется. Вот и пришлось использовать call().